# access django model fields label and help_text

Tags: django

I have something like this:

```
class ContactData(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=u"Name", help_text=u"Please enter your name...",null=True, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=u"Phone number", null=True, blank=False)
```

I would like to show a field's label and help_text in template (that is - just access it from view).
Can this be done?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
unicode(ContactData._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name)
unicode(ContactData._meta.get_field('name').help_text)

unicode(ContactData._meta.get_field('phone').verbose_name)
unicode(ContactData._meta.get_field('phone').help_text)
```

Comment: You can't access any of these fields in a template.

Comment: What is a language of such texts?

Answer (score 16):

I know this is old, but it deserves a full answer that can be used in templates.

If you need to use it in a template, the preferred method is to add model methods that get these values, such as:

```
from django.db import models
from six import text_type

class ContactData(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=u"Name", help_text=u"Please enter your name...",null=True, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=u"Phone number", null=True, blank=False)

    def __get_label(self, field):
        return text_type(self._meta.get_field(field).verbose_name)

    def __get_help_text(self, field)
        return text_type(self._meta.get_field(field).help_text)

    @property
    def name_label(self):
        return self.__get_label('name')

    @property
    def name_help_text(self):
        return self.__get_help_text('name')

    @property
    def phone_label(self):
        return self.__get_label('phone')

    @property
    def phone_help_text(self):
        return self.__get_help_text('phone')
```

Then, let us say `instance` is your object in a template, this is your label

```
<label for="id_phone">{{ instance.phone_label }}</label>
<div id="id_phone">{{ instance.phone }}</div>
```

Alternatively, you could create a template tag to do this, but the model method is clearer and keeps the model self contained.

Comment: Oof. You end up doing a method for every field in the model!

Comment: You could use a generator function that will generate all of these methods with 3 lines, but for this question, it is better to illustrate the process with verbosity.

Comment: @miigotu You took the words outta my mouth!  I was thinking a good use case of this solution would be a mixin, which would add properties for any help text and what I will call "choice" fields, meaning any field where "choices" is passed to its constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
model_instance.name.field.help_text
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'field'` for `model_instance.name.field`

Comment: Tried this with Django 2.0 -  but in a template, nowadays,  this data is not available...

Answer (score 1):

[django-etc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-etc) application has `model_field_verbose_name` and `model_field_help_text` template tags to access the data you asked from templates: http://django-etc.rtfd.org/en/latest/models.html#model-field-template-tags

Answer (score 1):

Example from a view:

```
return render(
    request,
    'projects/create_edit_project.html',
    {
        'form': form,
        'model_field_meta_data': 
            extract_model_field_meta_data(form),
    }
)
```

`extract_model_field_meta_data` extracts `help_text` for each model field referenced by the `ModelForm` `form`:

```
def extract_model_field_meta_data(form):
    """ Extract meta-data from the data model fields the form is handling. """
    meta_data = dict()
    for field_name, field_data in form.base_fields.items():
        meta_data[field_name] = {
            'help_text': getattr(field_data, 'help_text', '')
        }
    return meta_data
```

Then in the template:

```
<p class="help-block">{{ model_field_meta_data.title.help_text }}</p>
```

`title` is a field in the model.

Comment: If you have a form you also have the labels already...  
But this could ab a simple workaround - even if it's not an editing view, you can create a form for an object and put it in the context to provise the verbose name

Answer (score 0):

You can show this as follows:

```
>>> ContactData._meta.fields
[<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: name>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: phone>]
>>> ContactData._meta.fields[1].help_text
u'Please enter your name...'
```

Comment: The question qwas how to use this in a template - _meta is not accessible in template

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `help_text` in a template, you can do it using a custom tag:

**app/models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(help_text="This is the help text")
```

**app/templatetags/custom.py**

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def help_text(instance, field):
    return instance._meta.get_field(field).help_text
```

**app/templates/app/model_detail.html**

```
{% load custom %}

<p>{{ object|help_text:"field_name" }}</p>
```

Results in:

```
<p>This is the help text</p>
```